# How can i set the name of IE Extension (BHO In IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, bho

How Can i Set the Name of the BHO appear in IE Extension (e.g Manage Addons).. The Name that Appear in the Internet Explorer Addons list is the Namespace of my program when i attach it with regasm.exe. how can i set the name of that.?...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a C# BHO, and was struggling with this very same question. If you're working with C#, one approach that can be taken is to add code similar to the following in the method that is marked with the ComRegisterFunction attribute. This will set the appropriate registry key value so that the name that you desire will be reflected in the Manage Add-Ons screen.

```
using (key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\" + type.GUID.ToString("B")))
{
    key.SetValue(string.Empty, "My BHO Name Here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Include a [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx) resource.
2. [Sign your DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: How to add VERSIONINFO for a managed addon written in C#?? The code provided is in C++ and is valid only for Native addons like activex etc..Please correct me if i am wrong but i have sign my dlls but still i have the exact same issue for .Net based Managed Addon for IE,.

Answer (score 1):

No way to set the name? The name showing in the "Manage Add-Ons" window seems to be picked up from the BHO's C# class fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

This information is stored in .rgs file in your project. Look for a string like

ForceRemove {29DFE920-26AD-4377-8FCB-0E7A34A41199} = s 'NameIEBHO Class'

Comment: This answer is eerily similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5979352/744014).