# How to set the name of an bho (visible in the addon options in ie)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

How can I rename the name of a browser helper object. The normal information in the properties of the dll are all fine. However when I open Internet Explorer to view the Addons the name of my Addon is `NameIEBHO Class`

- The DLL is signed
- The VERSIONINFO is set (it includes CompanyName, FileDescription, FileVersion, InternalName, LegalCopyright, OriginalFilename, ProductName and ProductVersion)

What do I have to modify to change the name shown in Internet Explorer?

The Information in [How can i set the name of IE Extension (BHO In IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763988/how-can-i-set-the-name-of-ie-extension-bho-in-ie) did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in .rgs file in your project. Look for a string like

```
ForceRemove {29DFE920-26AD-4377-8FCB-0E7A34A41199} = s 'NameIEBHO Class'
```

Comment: thanks :) i found it myself by trial and error. A great place to put the name of a plugin.