# Change the name in disabling an IE toolbar addon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, bho, add-on

Please take a look.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/stoI7.jpg

I have read this post
[How to set the name of an bho (visible in the addon options in ie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647437/how-to-set-the-name-of-an-bho-visible-in-the-addon-options-in-ie)

But I can't find .rgs file or ForceRemove in my project

Also, how to make it a verified addons?

Thanks.

ps. I am using VS2010 with C#

Answer (score 0):

For verifying the add On, you need sign the IE BHO assembly using signtool with a proper certificate obtained from any third party certification.

usage f signtool:

SignTool sign /fMyCert.pfx /pMyPassword MyControl.exe

Where .pfx file is the one which you get it from third party certificate store

password - password for pfx

MyControl.exe .....here you have pass in your IE BHO dll name...

Hope this one helps you....